# Random positioning in Swift

Tags: swift, random

How would I create an arc4random thing? Like in previous versions I've seen

```
int blank = arc4random(5)
```

But how would I do it in the most recent version of Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let maxNumber = 10
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNumber)))
```